# Remove all taxes in WooCommerce for a min cart total and specific countries

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, tax

we need to charge 0 VAT for UK orders that are greater than 150 euro including shipping and payment gateway fees but excluding the 20% normal VAT.

So if a British residential address orders something at 130 and shipping and payment gateway fees are 9 then we charge VAT so the customer pays 139+9+20% VAT, but, if the order is 130 and shipping and payment gateway fees are 23 so a total of 153 without VAT we charge no tax.

I created this but still, it's taxing shipping fees and PayPal added fees also are getting taxed, my head is minced really thought I'd reach out for suggestions.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals','auto_add_tax_for_room', 10, 1 );
function auto_add_tax_for_room( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return; 
    
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['data']->get_price('edit') * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    $subtotal = intval($subtotal);
    

    if($shipping_country!='GB' || $subtotal < 125) return;
    
    $percent = 0;
    // Calculation
    $surcharge = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)
   foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // get product price
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'Zero rate' ); // Above 2500
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking into it now thank you!

Comment: I found a much more easy way to achieve your goal… Some feed back on the answer below will be appreciated please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hook `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` is just for cart items and the tax class here only apply to products as `$cart_item['data']` is the `WC_Product` Object.

If your product prices are set without taxes, there is another alternative much more simpler that will remove all taxes when your conditions are met.

Try the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'set_customer_tax_exempt' );
function set_customer_tax_exempt( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;

    $min_amount = 150; // Minimal cart amount
    $countries  = array('GB'); // Defined countries array

    $subtotal   = floatval( $cart->cart_contents_total );
    $shipping   = floatval( $cart->shipping_total );
    $fees       = floatval( $cart->fee_total );
    $total      = $subtotal + $shipping + $fees; // cart total (without taxes including shipping and fees)

    $country    = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $country    = empty($country) ? WC()->customer->get_billing_country() : $country;
    $vat_exempt = WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt();
    $condition  = in_array( $country, $countries ) && $total >= $min_amount;

    if ( $condition && ! $vat_exempt ) {
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( true ); // Set customer tax exempt
    } elseif ( ! $condition && $vat_exempt ) {
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false ); // Remove customer tax exempt
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'remove_customer_tax_exempt' );
function remove_customer_tax_exempt( $order_id ) {
    if ( WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt() ) {
        WC()->customer->set_is_vat_exempt( false );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: It's working but not with Paypal method and other payment methods where we charge extra fees for, Paypal is selected the VAT goes back to normal again.

Comment: @Joe Anyways this is the right way… I can't guess how you calculate the fees in paypal, don't you think (there are a lot of different paypal plugins that you can enable in WooCommerce)… So you should add in your question please the related details about paypal fees (and custom code if there is any).

Comment: Your solution has been extremely helpful to my WooCommerce issues.

Comment: @Joe Welcome! take care and good recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to LoicTheAztec help I made some changes ended up using the following and it worked to fix the UK taxes issues

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals','auto_add_tax_for_room', 10, 1 );
function auto_add_tax_for_room( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return; 
    
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['data']->get_price('edit') * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    $subtotal = intval($subtotal);  

    if($shipping_country!='GB' || $subtotal < 125) return;
    
    $percent = 0;
    // Calculation
    $surcharge = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percent / 100;

    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)
   foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // get product price
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_price();

        $cart_item['data']->set_tax_class( 'Zero rate' ); 
       
    }
    return;
}

function flat_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    $shipping_country = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
    
    $subtotal = 0;
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $subtotal += $cart_item['data']->get_price('edit') * $cart_item['quantity'];
    }
    $subtotal = intval($subtotal);
    
    if($shipping_country!='GB' || $subtotal < 125) return $rates;
    
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ){
        if ( 'free_shipping' !== $rate->method_id ) {
            $has_taxes = false;
            $taxes = [];
 
            // Taxes rate cost (if enabled)
            foreach ($rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax){
                if( $tax > 0 ){
                    $has_taxes = true;
                    $taxes[$key] = 0; // Set to 0 (zero)
                }
            }
            if( $has_taxes )
                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = 0;
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```